# Xcode: Launch screens may not set custom classnames when is assign to view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, launch-screen, xcode9.4

I'm trying to implement an animation before I load the application. I thought I can do it in the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` but when assign the viewcontroller in the LaunchScreen.storyboard to a viewcontroller class I get this error:

```
Illegal Configuration: Launch screens may not set custom classnames
```

[image]

I also tried to create a new view controller inside of my mainStoryboard but at the moment I assign the viewcontroller to a viewcontroller class I got the same error.

My question to you guys is how can I implement an animation when the application is loading without having this error ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: You cannot do _anything_ in the launch screen. It is shown _before your app runs_. It's just a picture. You have no code at this point. The launch screen is not a splash screen. It's just a "blank" to cover the half second while the app gets started from the springboard. If you want a splash screen, make a splash screen _in the app_.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create any animations inside the launch screen VC , it's static that ios displays it until your app loads , you need to create an initial VC for this , then after the animation finishes navigate to the actual content